# How to add additional id on my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fadeout = $('#1');
    function runIt() {
        fadeout.delay(500).animate({ opacity: '+1' }, 1000);
        fadeout.delay(500).animate({ opacity: '-0.5' }, 1000, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
});
```

Can you please help me what is the proper way of having a multiple "ID" in one function? The code above is working however I want my function to only have one since I'm using this JavaScript code many times.

Let's say the ID I want to include is `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, `#4`, `#5`

```
var fadeout = $('#1', '#2', '#3'. '#4'. '#5');
```

or making additional variable. However it's not working. Can you please help me? It is working but I want my code to be efficient.

Thank you!

Comment: instead of adding id add class if you want same thing to happen on all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be to add same class to all your html elements. And then select all elements with that class.

```
<div id="1" class="someClass"></div>
<div id="2" class="someClass"></div>
<div id="3" class="someClass"></div>
<div id="4" class="someClass"></div>
<div id="5" class="someClass"></div>

<script>
    var fadeout = $('.someClass');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through array of ids and perform runIt function on each:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fadeout = ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5'];
    for (i=0;i<fadeout.length;i++) {
      runIt(fadeout[i])
    }

    function runIt(id) {
        $(id).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '+1' }, 1000);
        $(id).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '-0.5' }, 1000, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just like following:

```
var fadeouts = $('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5');
$.each(fadeouts, function(index, fadeout){
   runIt(fadeout);
});
function runIt(fadeout) {
  fadeout.delay(500).animate({opacity:'+1'}, 1000);
  fadeout.delay(500).animate({opacity:'-0.5'}, 1000, runIt);
}
```

But I recommend using "class" instead of "id" like this:

```
<div id="1" class="fadeout">1</div>
<div id="2" class="fadeout">2</div>
<div id="3" class="fadeout">3</div>
<div id="4" class="fadeout">4</div>

var fadeouts = $('.fadeout');
$.each(fadeouts, function(index, fadeout){
   runIt(fadeout);
});
function runIt(fadeout) {
  fadeout.delay(500).animate({opacity:'+1'}, 1000);
  fadeout.delay(500).animate({opacity:'-0.5'}, 1000, runIt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function used by owner object:

```
function runIt() {
  $(this).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '+1' }, 1000);
  $(this).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '-0.5' }, 1000, runIt);
}
```

and then invoke it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#1 #2 #3').each(runIt);
  :
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow tuna's answer if you have option to put class in div tags. If you have no options then you can try my code below::

**HTML**

```
<div id="1">Hi</div>
<div id="2">Hiii</div>
<div id="3">Hiii</div>
<div id="4">Hiiii</div>
<div id="5">Hiiii</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var fadeout = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        function runIt() {
            $.each(fadeout, function (index, value) {
                $('#'+value).delay(500).animate({
                    opacity: '+1'
                },
                1000);
                $('#'+value).delay(500).animate({
                    opacity: '-0.5'
                },
                1000, runIt);
            });
        }
        runIt();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pass the id to the function.

Something like:

```
function runIt(id) {
   $(id).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '+1' }, 1000);
   $(id).delay(500).animate({ opacity: '-0.5' }, 1000);
}
runIt("#1");
runIt("#2");
runIt("#3");
runIt("#4");
runIt("#5");
```

On the other hand, you could also wrap them by adding a class, and then calling the runIt(class) function on that class